# Prefix try keyword with two underscore in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

All, Forgive me I am a newbie into the C++ world from C# and Java, I found it is common that underscore is used to prefixed variables or keywords in the C++ code. like function parameter `_In` and `__try` . I don't know what is the difference between with and without underscore prefix. Could someone please give me a something to read. thanks.

Best Regards.

Comment: Neither of those are part of standard C++. They're Microsoft extensions.

Comment: ... for structured exception handling. (__try)

Comment: :) +1  thanks, What do they use for?

Comment: @joe.wang For `__try` check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/swezty51.aspx). The `_In` is a "[SAL annotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx)". These annotations are used by some static analysis tools included with Microsoft compilers to help improve code correctness and detect bugs.

Comment: Duplicate of [c++ try-catch statement vs __try/__except](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600507/c-try-except-statement) and [What is __in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973239/what-is-in-and-wsaapi)

Comment: Note: all symbols starting with double underbars are reserved for compiler usage, so if you see a symbol like __try, you know it has to be a compiler specific feature